# Windows/Ubuntu dual boot - no option menu, immediately boots Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, boot, grub

This would be a [duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/599773/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-no-menu-to-choose-os) if any answer in this question worked for me. So here is what I did so far:

1. I created free space on the disk using the windows disk management tool
2. When installing ubuntu, I selected the "other" option since tutorials were advising against the automatic "install ubuntu alongside windows".
3. I created a `/` partition and a swap partition. And clicked continue. And followed the rest of the Ubuntu installation steps.

Now whenever I start my PC, ubuntu is immediately booted. So according to the [already mentioned question](https://superuser.com/questions/599773/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-no-menu-to-choose-os) I tried:

1. Opening `/etc/default/grub` I found this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

2. So I tried changing `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` first to `menu` and then (since that did not work) to `countdown`. In neither case I would get a menu. Before restarting I would use: `sudo update-grub` and get

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

---

Other remarks:

- This is my first time installing a linux distribution so I barely understand what I am doing, but I tried to double check everything. And I am very sure that I haven't touched the windows partition during installation. And starting windows still worked after reducing its partition to get free space.
- The ubuntu log in screen is extremely laggy. This is probably independent from this problem but I thought I should mention it. I intend to try out suggestions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144729/keyboard-and-mouse-are-extremely-slow-lagging-in-ubuntu-18-04s-login-screen) after fixing this problem.

Comment: " I selected the "other" option since tutorials were advising against the automatic "install ubuntu alongside windows". In my experience, letting Ubuntu complete the installation automatically works well, at least since v. 16.04.

Comment: Since installing Ubuntu, have you run software update? In my situation, this updated the grub menu with Ubuntu/advanced/memtest/windows 7, where I could select what I want. However, I installed Ubuntu on a separate HDD, which is more controllable (as you can select drive/OS boot order if grub fails to).