# Bios/Grub/UEFI only displayed when DVI monitor is connected, black screen for HDMI

Tags: bios, grub, hdmi, uefi, dvi

So I recently installed ubuntu on my pc as a dual boot and ran into some [issues](https://superuser.com/q/1525848/1140736), in short: I could not get the Grub options for Ubuntu/Windows to work and was always immediately thrown into Ubuntu.

after a discussion in the comments from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1124686/1044780), I was advised to remove everything and install both windows and ubuntu from scratch.

Now at the time I did not want to follow through, as it was the end of that weekend. Next weekend I realized that it is quite hard to wipe a hard drive, if the running system is still using it. So I tried accessing Grub again. I noticed that the screen simply stayed black if I used 'esc' during startup. I didn't really pay attention to that at first. But now I followed the hunch, that my monitor was somehow not displaying the menu. Plugging in my old monitor with a dvi cable and removing the new monitor, resulted in me getting to the boot menu. In particular I was able to boot into windows. I encountered some more oddities:

- Curiously using the "recovery" boot option for ubuntu cleared away my login lags, but whenever I use the normal boot option, they came back
- there where two ubuntu options. The second caused a crash.
- I ran some diagnostics, updated the bios etc. from the hp diagnostics tool and then tried to boot with the new monitor connected via HDMI again. Now the screen just stayed black instead of throwing me right into Ubuntu

```
Old monitor: Asus 24" ?? from 2011
New monitor: LG 27UK600-W
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8
Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0, 256 bits) 
Ubuntu: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
```

There should actually be an nvidia graphics card, but this is displayed in the settings, so I think that the dvi connection might go to the onboard graphics card. I'll try connecting the asus with an hdmi cable and see what results I get from that.

UPDATE: after installing nvidia drivers, the fan speed is way down and now I actually get
`Graphics: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2`

But I simply can not get the damn hdmi connection to work anymore.

Comment: Did you check that the monitor is using the correct HDMI input? Some can be reluctant to do it automatically. Is the BIOS set to use the PCIe graphics card instead of the on-board graphics?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, I can get it to work if I plug it in _after_ I booted the pc using the older monitor. But not as the only screen. And the nvidia card is now displayed in the settings details, so I would assume yes. What is even weirder is that both the dvi and the hdmi connectors are on the graphics card

Comment: If you run it with both monitors (DVI and HDMI) connected, is there any option in Ubuntu to select a primary monitor? The intent being to tell the graphics card which one to default to. Ah, it looks like someone's wanted to do that previously: [How to choose default output port (boot screen) in a nvidia card?](https://askubuntu.com/q/503707)

Comment: @AndrewMorton yeah that is pretty much it, and now I have actually gotten them to work starting them up together, but it still shows the boot menu exclusively on the dvi screen. And 'Make this the primary screen' from that answer, is already ticked. So up until the login everything is on the dvi only, and once I logged in it switches to hdmi being the primary monitor. That said: I do not really know how I gotten them to work. I just repeatedly restarted I guess.

Comment: Interesting fact: the loginscreen of ubuntu is dvi only, but the windows login is on the other monitor already. And looking through the bios settings, I found a setting: 'integrated graphics card deactivated at startup'. That explains why the ubuntu login was so laggy until I installed the nvidia driver. Apparently ubuntus log in screen is "in the bios" while windows login screen is "after the bios". I guess I will look for bios updates

Comment: I have a suspicion that the graphics card itself eventually learns what is intended to be first, although I have nothing to back that up apart from displays eventually seeming to end up the way I mean them to through having them plugged/unplugged at boot several times.